# Dates of all Orders , ordered desc

Tags: symfony, controller, sql-order-by

I want to sort the Dates of all orders, in a descending list. for each user, I was thinking of using orderBy, currently I am only returning all dates. I was wondering if this is possible. Since I am not doing it using a query

NOTE: I do now the orderby line doesn't work

```
 foreach($users as $user)
  {

    foreach ($orders as $order) {
     if($order->getCustomer()->getId() == $user->getId()){

        $orderDates = $order->getDate();
        $ordered = $orderDates->orderBy('date' ,'DESC');

     }
    }
```

Comment: what you want to achieve? an array containing the date sorted? You can't obtain it with a query with a where condition on the user_id and sort by date?

Comment: What I eventually want to achieve is get the latest order per user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `usort` [cf php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
  $ad = new DateTime($a);
  $bd = new DateTime($b);

  if ($ad == $bd) {
    return 0;
  }

  return $ad < $bd ? -1 : 1;
}
```

Then in your code :

```
usort($orderDates, "cmp");
```